# PyCharm new project test runner default to Twisted Trial

Tags: unit-testing, pycharm

When ever I create a new project or open a old one in PyCharm the test runner default to Twisted Trial.

I did some search and found that I can change project level default by Setting->Tools->Python Integrated Tools-> Default test runner

But not able to change the global default test runner for PyCharm.

The "Tools" option is not available in "Default Settings".

How to set up PyCharm so that the default test runner is "Unittests".

PyCharm Version - 2018.1 Community Edition
Python2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, **Integrated Tools** submenu is not available in default settings so there's no way to set this option globally, please vote for the corresponding ticket in PyCharm bug tracker: [PY-20243](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-20243).